# install joomla 4 ubuntu 21.04

Tags: apache2

```bsh
$ sudo apt install apache2 libapache2-mod-php openssl php-imagick php-gd php-imap php-intl php-json php-ldap php-mbstring php-mysql php-pgsql php-smbclient php-ssh2 php-sqlite3 php-xml php-zip
```

```bsh
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package php-smbclient is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'php-smbclient' has no installation candidate
```

Answer (score 2):

The `php-smbclient` package is only available [in the 18.04 Universe repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=php-smbclient), so cannot be installed on 21.04 without adding a 3rd-party repo, such as [the ondrej PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php/+index?batch=75&memo=150&start=150).

You can add this to your system like so:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt update
```

From here you will be able to install the `php-smbclient` package.